# vector push_back pushing wrong value

Tags: c++, stl

In the lines 39-41,in the first for loop, the value being shown in the console is different from the value being pushed into the vector. If you provide the input as:-
3
2 3 1
The value of variable a is shown to be 5, 6 and 4. But when i'm printing the vector on the screen it showing different value.
The code is :-

```
#include<stdio.h>

    #include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<vector>
    #include<algorithm>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        unsigned long n;
        //int *arr;
        cin>>n;
        int arr[n];
        vector<bool> dec[n];
        vector<long> inc[n];
        //cout<<sizeof(arr)<<"\n";
        for(unsigned long i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
        vector<long>  sum[n];
        //vector<long> inclusive;
        //long long f[n][n];
        int incount=0;
        int interval=0;
        long  maxf=0;


        for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(i==j){
                    dec[i].push_back(true);
                inc[i].push_back(arr[j]);
                sum[i].push_back(arr[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"summing:"<<arr[j]+sum[i].back();
                    long a=arr[j]+sum[i].back();
                    cout<<"value of a: "<<a;
                    sum[i].push_back(a);
                    if(arr[j]<arr[j-1] ){
                        dec[i].push_back(false);
                    inc[i].push_back(inc[i].back());
                    }
                    else{
                        inc[i].push_back(inc[i].back()+arr[j]);
                        dec[i].push_back(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
            //inclusive[0][i]=0;


        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            vector<long>::iterator it;
            it=sum[i].begin();

            for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
                cout<<*it<<" ";
            it++;
    cout<<"\n";     
            }
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            vector<long>::iterator it;
            it=inc[i].begin();

            for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
                cout<<*it<<" ";
            it++;
    cout<<"\n";     
            }

            cout<<maxf<<" "<<incount;

    }
```

Comment: Don't use `int arr[n]` unless `n` is a compile time constant.  Use `std::vector<int> arr{n}`.  Similarly for a 2D array, use `std::vector<std::vector<long>> inc{n};`

Comment: okk, sir. thnx for the suggestion. but could you tell me why a different value is being pushed into the vector than the one provided in push_back() method. I mean isn't it obvious to find the value somewhere in the vector even if it's on the wrong index. when i printed the vector there was no such value as shown on the console. i was hoping if i didn't have to restructure my code.thnx for d response

Comment: You need to reduce the size of the problem.  You push_back into three different vectors.  Which one has the wrong values?  What values does it have?  What values do you think it should have?  (Also, fix the formatting of your code - it's currently unreadable.)

Comment: all of them has wrong values. for instance the in the sum vector index 0 should have  2 ,5, 6 but the  resultant values are 2, 2, 2. nd sorry about the formatting but i did format it while posting.

Comment: OK.  Let me be a bit clearer: [edit] your question to fix the formatting, and remove all but the `sum` vector.

Comment: If you fix the formatting, you will see what the problem is.  It's not what you think it is.

Comment: Final suggestion:  Rather than loop j=[i,n) and then test j==i inside the loop, do the special case first, and then loop j=[i+1,N).  This makes it much clearer that references to `arr[j-1]` and `inc[i].back()` must be valid.

Comment: `cin>>n;` followed by `int arr[n];` is not valid C++.

Answer (score 0):

> The value of variable a is shown to be 5, 6 and 4. But when i'm
>   printing the vector on the screen it showing different value.

How ? Can you show the output ?

I'm getting exactly same output by debugging values as it stored in variable `a`

Note: you are doing 
`long a=arr[j]+sum[i].back();`
adding variable `arr[j]` value with last element of vector `sum[i].back()` and store it in `a`.

try to print both `arr[j]` and `sum[i].back()` value - you will get the idea about how the value is calculated in `a`

** variable `a` do not store only vector value that's why they are not equal

Comment: okk..i got the problem m incrementing the iterator outside the loop that's why its showing the same value at an index.

Comment: i mean outside the nested loop in the last section of the code